# Quit VBScript if Statement is True

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I have a VBScript that creates an Folder within outlook. It runs in a login script the issue I am having now is that if the script runs again i get an error cant create folder that's because the folder already exists. Could anyone help me with creating an if statement to mention if the folder exists then quit.

```
`Const olFolderInbox = 6

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`

`strFolderName = objFolder.Parent
Set objMailbox = objNamespace.Folders(strFolderName)`

`Set objNewFolder = objMailbox.Folders.Add("Search")
objNewFolder.WebViewURL = "www.google.com"
objNewFolder.WebViewOn = True`
```

Comment: Thanks Andy for the help it worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You can temporarily turn off error handling, then try and refer to the folder. If this fails, giving an error, then the folder doesn't exist and you can create it.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objNewFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Search")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    'the folder doesn't exist, create it
End If
```

You could wrap this error-code around the `.Add("Search")` call if you prefer.

Comment: Just to clarify Andy's good post:      `On Error Resume Next` disables VBScript's error handling (although it will still set the Err.Number and Err.Message properties of the Err object, which is why Andy's code works - it can still test to see if Err.Number > 0 ) -- it keeps on this way until it sees `On Error Goto 0` and resumes it's normal error behaviors.

Comment: Alternative to checking the Error code: `If objNewFolder Is Nothing Then : ' Create the folder`